# How can I update multiple WordPress post title at once in the admin area?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Manually, I will have to click on the Quick Edit button for each post. Update the title field and then click update.

I tried to do it using some JavaScript code in the console:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
var allPosts = document.querySelectorAll("tr.status-publish td div.row-actions a.editinline");

for(var i=0; i < allPosts.length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll("tr.status-publish td div.row-actions a.editinline")[0].click();

    var titleInput = document.querySelectorAll("tr.quick-edit-row-post .input-text-wrap input.ptitle")[0];

    if(titleInput.value.indexOf("Old Value") > 0) {
      titleInput.value = titleInput.value.replace("Old Value", "New Value");
    }

    document.querySelectorAll("div.inline-edit-save .save")[0].click();
}
}, 2000);
```

It works but seems a bit hacky because the code keeps clicking on update for a single post multiple times and it seems to randomly succeed or fail.

I think it has something to do with AJAX. Could anyone guide me on how I should proceed? What do I need to change in this code? Is there some other better way to update multiple titles at once?